# Excel macro to copy rows with unique name in column A to accordingly named wosksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I am an Excel novice, and would appreciate help with a macro which does the following.

[image: The user pastes data into the Input sheet.]

There are a total of 58 genes (column A) with 2 entries for each gene. The image only shows 4 genes.

Upon running the macro (via a shortcut key), the user will be prompted to enter a sample number (Sample1 in this example), and then the row for each gene is to be copy-pasted into their respective sheets (already created). The genes are all uniquely named.
In each of the gene sheets, the sample number is to be filled in column A.

[image: Gene1]

I am not able to post more than 2 screenshots. The sheets for the other genes should contain the 2 rows for that gene with "Sample1" in column A.

Once the macro has finished copying the rows to the 58 sheets (for the 58 genes), it should return to the Input sheet and delete the previously pasted data. The user should the be allowed to paste the data for the next sample, run the macro, enter the sample number when prompted, and the gene data for that sample gets copied into the next 2 lines of their respective gene sheets.

There is data for thousands of samples to be databased, and I'm hoping to get a macro which is able to do this.

Edit: The code now (thanks to Mrig) is as follows:

```
Sub Macro1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, currLastRow
    Dim ws As Worksheet, currWS As Worksheet
    Dim SampleID As String

    SampleIDform.Show

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Set currWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
        currLastRow = currWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        With ws.Range("A1", "D" & lastRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=currWS.Name
            .Offset(1, 0).Copy currWS.Range("A" & currLastRow)
            .AutoFilter
            Range("A" & currLastRow).Value = SampleID
        End With
    Next i

    ws.Range("A2", "D" & lastRow).ClearContents

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    SampleID = txtSampleID.Value
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

I've added in the line `Range("A" & currLastRow).Value = SampleID` to the with loop, but I am unable to get the SampleID included with every sheet at column A.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of: [Excel & VBA: Copy rows into a new sheet based on cell value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070625/excel-vba-copy-rows-into-a-new-sheet-based-on-cell-value) on StackOverflow

Comment: I had started adding in the separate 58 worksheet names into the AutoFilter criteria following the answer posted by user2140261 in that link when Mrig posted the below answer, and saved me the trouble. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do for you:

**Assumptions:**
**1.** Input sheet is your first worksheet in the workbook you are working
**2.** All the sheets have the header `Gene | Allele | Reads | Sequence`

```
Sub DataToSheets()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, currLastRow
    Dim ws As Worksheet, currWS As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Set currWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
        currLastRow = currWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        With ws.Range("A1", "D" & lastRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=currWS.Name
            .Offset(1, 0).Copy currWS.Range("A" & currLastRow)
            .AutoFilter
        End With
    Next i

    ws.Range("A2", "D" & lastRow).ClearContents

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Made some changes in answer given by @user2140261 in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070625/excel-vba-copy-rows-into-a-new-sheet-based-on-cell-value) mentioned by @Sun in comments.

Comment: Thank you for the short and efficient code. It works very well!

Comment: I am now trying to capture the sample ID as input from the user.
I created a user form "SampleIDform", with a textbox "txtSampleID", and an Ok button with the following command:
Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    SampleID = txtSampleID.Text
    Unload Me
End Sub

Comment: @Ramani - I guess I've given an answer to your original question, if that fulfills your requirement kindly accept it as an answer. For any other issue that is not related to above answer, you should ask another question.

Comment: and in the main module, have inserted the following lines:
Dim SampleID As String
SampleIDform.Show

and in the With loop, I've added the following line:
Range("A" & currLastRow).Value = SampleID

with the intention of adding the SampleID to each created row in all sheets.

When I run the macro, the user form shows, and executes after I click the Ok button, but the SampleID is not entered into column A of the separate Gene sheets. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: @Ramani - You'll have to use `SampleID = txtSampleID.Value'

Comment: Even after changing it to 'txtSampleID.Value', it still doesn't show up in the separate Gene sheets. The code for the with loop is as follows:
`With ws.Range("A1", "D" & lastRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=currWS.Name
            .Offset(1, 0).Copy currWS.Range("A" & currLastRow)
            .AutoFilter
            Range("A" & currLastRow).Value = SampleID
        End With`

Comment: Instead of `.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=currWS.Name` write `.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=SampleID`and....

Comment: instead of `.AutoFilter Range("A" & currLastRow).Value = SampleID` just write `.AutoFilter`

Comment: If this does not help, you'll have show me more code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mrig for all your input. I think I have solved my problems.
My code is as follows:

```
Sub DataToSheets()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, currLastRow
    Dim ws As Worksheet, currWS As Worksheet
    Dim SampleID As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    SampleID = InputBox("Key in Sample ID", "Sample ID")
    If (StrPtr(SampleID) = 0) Then
        MsgBox "You pressed cancel or [X]"
    ElseIf (SampleID = "") Then
        MsgBox "You did not enter anything"
    Else
    For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Set currWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
        currLastRow = currWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        With ws.Range("A1", "D" & lastRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=currWS.Name
            .Offset(1, 0).Copy currWS.Range("A" & currLastRow)
            .AutoFilter
            currWS.Range("A" & currLastRow).Value = SampleID
            currWS.Range("A" & currLastRow + 1).Value = SampleID
        End With
    Next i
    End If
    ws.Range("A2", "D2" & lastRow).ClearContents

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Sub PasteValues()
'
' PasteValues Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'    
    On Error Resume Next

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Call DataToSheets

End Sub
```

I couldn't get the input from the userform recognized for some reason, and so resorted to using the InputBox way to get user input. The lines `currWS.Range("A" & currLastRow).Value = SampleID` and `currWS.Range("A" & currLastRow + 1).Value = SampleID` include the entered SampleID in column A of the 2 rows copied from the Input sheet, for every gene sheet. If there is a more efficient way of doing this, please let me know.

All the user has to do is to have the data copied, open the Excel file, and run the shortcut key, and then enter the SampleID in the InputBox.

Thank you all, especially Mrig!!

Comment: Great! Good to see you making changes in the code as per your requirements.